# Content present in the ngSwitchDefault is not updating every time when i change switch variable condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have layout page as below. Layout is responsible for loading all routs in my project. When we use view1 that will load default condition. same way view2, view3 loads its own condition.

```
 <ng-container [ngSwitch]="routeData?.layout">
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'view2'"> Some HTml and <router-outlet></router-outlet></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'view3'"> Some HTml and <router-outlet></router-outlet></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>Some HTml and <router-outlet></router-outlet></ng-container>
```

When i have been in the page which using the view1(default layout) and i am trying to navigate the other page which also using the view1. browser URL getting changed but Router-outlet not loading new page.
I have understood that when switch case is executing the same case which is not detecting any changes.

Could you please guys suggest any proper way to update switch case data or any good approach to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please create a minimal stack blitz example for this to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue i have solved using below approach.

```
<ng-template #temp>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-template>
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="routeData?.layout">
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'view2'"> Some HTml and <ng-container *templateOutlet="temp"></ng-container></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'view3'"> Some HTml and <ng-container *templateOutlet="temp"></ng-container></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>Some HTml and <ng-container *templateOutlet="temp"></ng-container></ng-container>
```